# @for directive issue when creating .grid.column classes

Tags: html, css, for-loop, sass

I am creating a grid layout using SCSS—specifically a `@for` directive in SCSS.

It's also important to note that I'm using numeric classes in my markup with the help of css escapes.

Here is my SCSS:

```
$columns: 12;
$column: 100% / $columns;

@for $i from 1 through $columns {
  @if $i == 10 {
    $i: 1 0;
  } @else if $i == 11 {
    $i: 1 1;
  } @else if $i == 12 {
    $i: 1 2;
  }

  .row .\3#{$i} .columns {
    width: $column * $columns;
  }
}
```

This compiles to the following:

```
.row .\31 .columns {
  width: 100%;
}
.row .\32 .columns {
  width: 100%;
}
.row .\33 .columns {
  width: 100%;
}
.row .\34 .columns {
  width: 100%;
}
.row .\35 .columns {
  width: 100%;
}
.row .\36 .columns {
  width: 100%;
}
.row .\37 .columns {
  width: 100%;
}
.row .\38 .columns {
  width: 100%;
}
.row .\39 .columns {
  width: 100%;
}
.row .\31 0 .columns {
  width: 100%;
}
.row .\31 1 .columns {
  width: 100%;
}
.row .\31 2 .columns {
  width: 100%;
}
```

My problem is with classes `.10`, `.11` and `.12`. As I have added the required space with an `@if` after the first number (as is usually required with css escapes), I now need to remove the second space after the second number. Is this possible in Sass/SCSS?

So if this was functioning as I wanted, single number classes would be written like so:

```
.row .\31 .columns { width: 100%; }
```

and multiple number classes would be written like so:

```
.row .\31 2.columns { width: 100%; }
```

I am aware that the css isn't particularly efficient when compiled. What I am really seeking in an answer is what is and is not possible with SCSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you basically want is to introduce a space always after the first digit of the number. So if it's `1`, you want `1_` and if it's `11` you want `1_1`.

The following snippets will help you achieve this. They are all from [Advances Sass list functions by Hugo Giraudel](https://hugogiraudel.com/2013/08/08/advanced-sass-list-functions/#adding-values-to-a-list), so make sure to check that out.

## Insert value at index `n` of a list

```
@function insert-nth($list, $index, $value) {
  $result: null;

  @if type-of($index) != number {
    @warn "$index: #{quote($index)} is not a number for `insert-nth`.";
  }

  @else if $index < 1 {
    @warn "List index 0 must be a non-zero integer for `insert-nth`";
  }

  @else if $index > length($list) {
    @warn "List index is #{$index} but list is only #{length($list)} item long for `insert-nth'.";
  }

  @else {
    $result: ();

    @for $i from 1 through length($list) {
      @if $i == $index {
        $result: append($result, $value);
      }

      $result: append($result, nth($list, $i));
    }
  }

  @return $result;
}
```

### Usage:

```
$list: a, b, d, e, f;
/* I want to add "c" as the 3rd index in the list */
$new-list: insert-nth($list, 3, c);   // a, b, c, d, e, f
```

## Convert list to string

```
@function to-string($list, $glue: '', $is-nested: false) {
  $result: null;

  @for $i from 1 through length($list) {
    $e: nth($list, $i);

    @if type-of($e) == list {
      $result: $result#{to-string($e, $glue, true)};
    }

    @else {
      $result: if($i != length($list) or $is-nested, $result#{$e}#{$glue}, $result#{$e});
    }
  }

  @return $result;
}
```

### Usage

```
$list: a, b, c d e, f, g, h;
$new-list: to-string($list);      // abcdefgh
$new-list: to-string($list, '-'); // a-b-c-d-e-f-g-h
```

---

So for your problem use `insert-nth` to insert a space at the second place in the list and transform the list to string by using an empty string as a separator. Then interpolate this string into your selector.

Comment: Perhaps I need to edit my question above. The space needs to be there for single number classes. The space needs to come after the character that is being escaped. e.g. .\31 .columns. So if I were to do as you suggest, then how do I introduce a space after single character/number classes? Is this then possible in Sass/SCSS? Please let me know if this doesn't make sense.

Comment: So I'm looking for the `@for` and `@if` to pump out this `.\31 .columns` (single character) and then this `.\31 1.columns` (double character). I am unsure how to do this in Sass/SCSS and can't find an answer/docs to assist.

Comment: I think I got it!

Comment: Thank you for this! Much appreciated. More complicated than I was expecting. But at least it's possible all in Sass eh!

Comment: Most of he times functions are just typecheckin though. The actual logic is not that far away of how'd you write it in any programming language.